# What is the full axiom of choice (with "$\in$" as the only atomic formula)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen the axiom of choice as $\forall X\left[\varnothing \notin X\implies \exists f\colon X\rightarrow \bigcup_{A\in X}A,~~~ \forall A\in X\,(f(A)\in A)\right]$.

But isn't there a version which doesn't need the definition of a function and of the union?

Comment: Functions and unions (and $\emptyset$ for that matter) are just abbreviations for longer expressions in the language of set theory, so you can always just "unpack" them - it's just that the expression you get will be longer and harder to read.

Comment: Yes and this is what I'm looking for, where to find an unpacked version, or how to form one by myself.

Comment: Hi! You can read Math.SE questions and answers on [the empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not), [the axiom of union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548958/axiom-of-union-in-zfc), and [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672913/how-does-zfc-define-functions), to see how to do each thing you want. The questions are not only about those things, but you should be able to glean what you need. As @NoahSchweber points out, this will be difficult to read, but if you don't care, have at it!

Comment: Are you happy that you could write down a formula to express "$f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$" or "$Y$ is equal to $\bigcup_{A \in X} A$" or "the value of $f(A)$ is $B$" and that sort of thing? The other "trick" you need is to sometimes add a new quantifier - for example, you can "unpack" a formula like $\varphi(f(A))$ to $(\exists B)((\text{the value of $f(A)$ is $B$}) \land \varphi(B))$. I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3727311/473276) answer might also be worth having a look at.

Comment: I think Zermelo used a variant with choice set.  That's a formulation where you have a set $S$ of non-empty mutually disjoint sets, and you want a set $C$ that intersects each member of $S$ in exactly one member.  It doesn't use function or union.  The functional formulation can be derived from it using Cartesian products and union.

Comment: $\in$ is not an atomic formula. $x\in x$, $x\in y$, $u\in x$ etc. are atomic formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is a set of pairwise disjoint sets, then there is a set $c$ whose intersection with each nonempty element of $a$ is a singleton.
$$\forall a\{\exists s\exists t\exists x\exists y[s\in a\land t\in a\land x\in s\land x\in t\land y\in s\land y\notin t]\lor\exists c\forall s\forall w[s\in a\land w\in s\to\exists x\forall y(y\in c\land y\in s\leftrightarrow\forall z(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y))]\}$$